# How to put whitespaces at url for request

Tags: java, jsp, parsing, url, get

I need to pass some parameters to url. Later I will extract it and I need exactly this words.

It's at `jsp` page:

```
     <li>
          <a href="<c:url value="/apartments?select=threestars"/>"><fmt:message key="nav.dropdown.threestars"/></a>
     </li>
```

I need exactly set `three stars` instead `threestars`, for later parsing.

How to put this whitespace, that it be compatible for get method, and was possibly to extract:

> String type = request.getParameter("select");

And value of type => `three stars`.

How to solve ***this issue***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you use %20 in place of a space it should be compatible with GET.

For example :

```
value="/apartments?select=three%20stars"
```

Comment: You can also use `+`: `three+stars`

Comment: @helderdarocha no you can't; a `+` is illegal in a query parameter

Comment: @fge not illegal. You can use `%20`, but also `+`. Some browsers generate `+`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

Comment: @helderdarocha do not mix form parameters with _query_ parameters!

Comment: It's a query string, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If it follows the URL spec, which it should, it should accept '+' or '%20'. Try it out.